# How to transform combinations of values in columns into individual columns?

Tags: python, pandas, columnsorting

I have a dataset (df), that looks like this:

| Date | ID | County Name | State | State Name | Product Name | Type of Transaction | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202105 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA | California | Shoes | Entry | 630 |
| 202012 | 10002 | Houston | TX | Texas | Keyboard | Exit | 5493 |
| 202001 | 11684 | Chicago | IL | Illionis | Phone | Disposal | 220 |
| 202107 | 12005 | New York | NY | New York | Phone | Entry | 302 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 202111 | 14990 | Orlando | FL | Florida | Shoes | Exit | 201 |

For every county, there are multiple entries for different Products, types of transactions, and at different dates, but not all counties have the same number of entries and they don't follow the same dates.

I want to recreate this dataset, such that:
1 - All counties have the same start and end dates, and for those dates where the county does not record entries, I want this entry to be recorded as NaN.
2 - The product names and their types are their own columns.

Essentially, this is how the dataset needs to look:

| Date | ID | County Name | State | State Name | Shoes, Entry | Shoes, Exit | Shoes, Disposal | Phones, Entry | Phones, Exit | Phones, Disposal | Keyboard, Entry | Keyboard, Exit | Keyboard, Disposal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202105 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA | California | 594 | 694 | 5660 | 33299 | 1110 | 5659 | 4559 | 3223 | 56889 |
| 202012 | 10002 | Houston | TX | Texas | 3420 | 4439 | 549 | 2110 | 5669 | 2245 | 39294 | 3345 | 556 |
| 202001 | 11684 | Chicago | IL | Illionis | 55432 | 4439 | 329 | 21190 | 4320 | 455 | 34059 | 44556 | 5677 |
| 202107 | 12005 | New York | NY | New York | 34556 | 2204 | 4329 | 11193 | 22345 | 43221 | 1544 | 3467 | 22450 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 202111 | 14990 | Orlando | FL | Florida | 54543 | 23059 | 3290 | 21394 | 34335 | 59660 | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Under the example, you can see how Florida does not record certain transactions. I would like to add the NaN such that the dataframe looks like this. I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Please use correct formatting for tables in Markdown. Please read [this post on how to use tables in posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post)

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen I tried using tables formatting but I think the table was too large. I went ahead and updated the tables as images.

Comment: Don't use images, it was just missing a newline between the text and table

Comment: @mozway My apologies! I am still new to asking questions on stack overflow. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Where do the numbers in the second dataframe come from?  How do you get, 594, 694, and 5660?  All I see up top is 630.

Comment: @TimRoberts The numbers in the second dataframe would be the Specific line values. For example, if the Type of Transaction is Exit and the Product is Shoes, and the quantity associated to that line is 600, it would be recorded under Shoes, Exit, 600

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, I don't think it does. These dataframes are being pivoted by rows, in general. I am trying to essentially merge Product Name and Transaction Type, and break these two columns into its groupings. Perhaps merging both of these columns is a start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially a `pivot`, with flattening of the MultiIndex:

```
(df
 .pivot(index=['Date', 'ID', 'County Name', 'State', 'State Name'],
        columns=['Product Name', 'Type of Transaction'],
        values='QTY')
 .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(map(','.join, d. columns), axis=1))
 .reset_index()
 )
```

Output:

```
     Date     ID  County Name State  State Name  Shoes,Entry  Keyboard,Exit  \
0  202001  11684      Chicago    IL    Illionis          NaN            NaN   
1  202012  10002      Houston    TX       Texas          NaN         5493.0   
2  202105  10001  Los Angeles    CA  California        630.0            NaN   
3  202107  12005     New York    NY    New York          NaN            NaN   

   Phone,Disposal  Phone,Entry  
0           220.0          NaN  
1             NaN          NaN  
2             NaN          NaN  
3             NaN        302.0
```

Comment: I have tried inputting this code into my dataset, and received the following error: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. Also tried adding aggfunc='first', in order to aggregate indexes but it didn't work!

Comment: Then you need to use `pivot_table`